# String json has null values

Tags: javascript, json, stringify

I am trying to `stringify` my json -

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < lines.length ; i++) {

    var label = lines[i];
    var value = 1;

    item = [];
    item["label"] = label;
    item["value"] = value;

    jsonObj.push(item);
}

var jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
```

During iteration, both `label` and `value` are being assigned accordingly with the correct values.

However `jsonString` is full of null values, why is this the case?

Comment: try `var item = {};`

Comment: You are creating a Array and not a object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `item = {};` and not `item = [];`.

The first is the object literal, and the second is the array literal.

For good measure, do `var items = {};`

Answer (score 2):

The case is that you create an array `item = []` then set its string properties.

Whereas `JSON.stringify` expects that something that looks like an array is an array, so it does not even try to iterate over its non-numeric properties.

The solution for you would be to replace it with an object `{}`

The excerpt from the specification:

```
If Type(value) is Object, and IsCallable(value) is false
    If the [[Class]] internal property of value is "Array" then
        Return the result of calling the abstract operation JA with argument value.
```

followed by

```
Let len be the result of calling the [[Get]] internal method of value with argument "length".
Let index be 0.
Repeat while index < len
    Let strP be the result of calling the abstract operation Str with arguments ToString(index) and value.
    If strP is undefined
        Append "null" to partial.
    Else
        Append strP to partial.
    Increment index by 1.
```

References:

- [15.12.3 stringify](http://es5.github.io/#x15.12.3)
- [15.12.3 stringify JA](http://es5.github.io/#JA)

Comment: Excellent references, manojlds got there just before however so will need to accept his answer.

Comment: @Ebikeneser so you prefer speed over quality and details level? Okay

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out, you'll need to make your item an object.  Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b9Lztn8b/) to get you started with an example.

```
var item;
var lines = ["a","b","c"];
var jsonObj = {};
jsonObj.items = [];

for (var i = 0 ; i < lines.length ; i++) {

    var label = lines[i];
    var value = 1;

    item = {};
   item["label"] = label;
   item["value"] = value;

    jsonObj.items.push(item);
    console.log(jsonObj);
}

var jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
console.log(jsonString);
```